# Use WYSIWYG Editor with PHP escape Method

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I am building a small/test CMS using Php and Mysql.
Everything is working amazingly on the adding, editing, deleting and displaying level, but after finishing my code, I wanted to add a WYSIWYG editor in the Admin back end.

My problem is that I am using escape method to hopefully make my form a bit more secure and try to escape injections, therefore when adding a styled text, image or any other HTML code in my Editor I am getting them printed as line codes on my page(Which is completely right to avoid attacks).

MY ESCAPE METHOD:

```
function e($text) {
return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');}
```

Is there any way to work around my escape method (which is think it should not be done because if I can do it every attacker could).

Or should I change my escape method to another method?

Comment: You can try `strip_tags()`. Read this manual here: [PHP: strip_tags (Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Thank you a lot C0dekid.php, Can you please formulate it as an answer so i can vote up and choose it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags()` to remove the unwanted tags. Read about it on this manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Example 1 (Based on the manual)

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph, <a href="#">With link</a>.</p>';
# Output: Test paragraph, With link. (Tags are stripped)
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

# Allow <p> and <a>
#Output: <p>Test paragraph, <a href="#">With link</a>.</p>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you are going to allow your users to put some formatting into the text they are going to create. For this you are going to add some WYSISWYG editor. But the question is how to distinguish the formatting and special characters which are allowed from what is not allowed. You need to clean up the text and leave only valid allowed formatting (HTML tags) and remove all malicious JavaScript or HTML.

This is not an easy task like it might sound at the first moment. I can see several approaches here.

1. Easiest solution to use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and specify what tags are allowed.

But please keep in mind that `strip_tags` is not perfect. Let me quote the manual here.

> Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or
>   broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.
>
> This function does not modify any attributes on the tags that you
>   allow using allowable_tags, including the style and onmouseover
>   attributes that a **mischievous user may abuse** when posting text that
>   will be shown to other users.

This is a known issue. And libraries exist which do a better cleanup of HTML and JS to prevent breaks.

2. A bit more complicated solution would be to use some advanced library to cleanup the HTML code. For example this might be [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Quote from the documentation

> HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious code (better known as
>   XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive whitelist, it
>   will also make sure your documents are standards compliant, something
>   only achievable with a comprehensive knowledge of W3C's
>   specifications.

The other libraries exist which solve the same task. You can check for example this [article where libraries are compared](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison). And finally you might choose the best one.

3. Completely different approach is to avoid users from writing HTML tags. Ask them to write some other markup instead like this is done on StackOverflow or Basecamp or GitHub. [Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) might be a good approach.

Using simple markup for text allows you to complete avoid issues with broken HTML and JavaScript cause you can escape everything and build HTML markup on your own.

The editor might look like the one I'm using to write this message :)

Comment: Sir Victor Smirnov, thank you for guiding me through my ongoing education. for the time being i will try to go with the Strip_tags solution as my piece of code is just for learning. on the other hand you provided me with a research material so i can go deeper and try to learn how to create the editor like the one we are using now because i think it will be the best solution to use on my next test. Again, thank you a lot

Comment: @PierreIrani you are welcome. I think HTML Purifier might be a better solution than strip_tags. But you are right you should made the decision keeping in mind all other requirements. This is why all approaches might make sense and be applicable.